# Exporting a raster object with a categorical legend

Tags: raster, r, legend, rasterization

I created a raster object (package raster in R) using the function rasterize starting from a shapefile of polygons. I passed as field a shapefile attribute (CODE) containing 37 landuse categories.

This is what I did in code:

```
myrast <- rasterize(x = shapefile, y = another_raster, field = shapefile$CODE)
```

The command converts the categorical variable into numbers from 1 to 37 and correctly create the raster.

Now I want to export the raster to see it in a GIS but I would like that a legend would be shown with the CODE and not with the number from 1 to 37.

How can I do this?

Comment: In what GIS? Raster values are always numerical. For representing attribute data, it is common to have a standalone file (eg., dbf) containing the attributes with the raster values as the linking value. You can do this by simply writing a csv flat file.

Comment: In QGIS. So when I write a GTiff with R how can I have the relative legend in QGIS?

Comment: You can use `rasterVis::levelplot()` as, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136330/legend-of-a-raster-map-with-categorical-data/20321664#20321664).

Comment: Thank you for this hint, this is good for doing what I want in R, but for the export in QGIS?